# Twitter Bootstrap tabbed form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a webpage with the Bootstrap framework. I want to have a single page, with a form that pops up and has two or three tabs on it. I want this,

[image: Bootstrap example]

The tabs for "The Markup", "The CSS", "The JavaScript". I have them showing up on the top left of the page like it's on the main navbar, but I can't get them anywhere else.

Ideally, I'd like them to be on top of a form and switch between the forms.

Another question that's probably elementary, but to get the buttons like I have them I used this code,

```
<div class="note-tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#navbar-fixed-html" data-toggle="tab"><strong>The Markup</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#navbar-fixed-css" data-toggle="tab"><strong>The CSS</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#navbar-fixed-js" data-toggle="tab"><strong>The JavaScript</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

What does it mean when the href field has a # at the front? This is from an example page at tutsplus and this is what came with the download. There isn't a separate html file for those, so what exactly is that linking to?

Thanks

UPDATE

Here is the form I have, I want to add tabs to the top of this form. One tab that selects this form and another tab that will select another form. The form is place in the middle of the page

http://jsfiddle.net/BS4Te/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # in the front of a element is called "**fragment**" and they allow you to move across the page.

You can get the popup with the next code:

The **HTML** code:

```
<div class="container-popup">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

The **CSS** code:

```
.container-popup {
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.popup {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #1abcb9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BS4Te/)**

---

If you want the less "intrusive code", you can use a pseudoelement, as follows:

Check this **[SECOND DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BS4Te/2/)**

As you can see in the below example, the HTML code has only one element:

```
<div class="popup">
```

Cheers!

---

**EDIT**: Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S42jP/)**. I only make it with one form, but I think that you'll catch the idea.

Cheers!

Comment: Ahhh okay, I understand the fragment element now.

I'm not sure that's what i'm looking for, I tried to add that in. Maybe I did it wrong. I want those tabs that reference the fragments I believe, but I want the fragments to be forms. Would a picture help this question any?

Comment: Technically, the # character isn't a "element" is an [identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: Ah okay, got it. Thanks. Can that be used with forms? I want it to be a form for address info, then another tab just to enter an email address.

Comment: Right, I see a blue box popup on the screen. I would like for that blue box popup to be my form, and add two tabs on top that are the same width as the box and switch between two different forms. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out what you want... If you "click" the element that has the fragment identifier, you want to "appear" a form? Then if you "click" another element with the fragment identifier, another form was displayed? That's what you want?

Comment: Please, if you can, edit your question with an online example. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a good site to do this =)

Comment: I added a demo, the fragment idea was really a side note. I don't know that I really need them for this. It was just a question I realized I had as I was typing this up, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I've edit the post! Sorry for the late. I have to go now! Hope it help you!

Comment: I believe that is almost what I needed! That will get me there, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Those href fields with # at the front link to id inside same HTML document

For example:

```
<a href="#section1">Go to Section 1</a>
```

Is link to id "section1"

```
<a id="section1">Here is Section 1</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have a a form tabbed that works quite well,

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs form-tabs">
    <li id="basic-list" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#form1">form 1</a>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="team_details-list"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#form2">form 2</a>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="identity_information-list"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#form3">form 3</a>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="address_details-list"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#form4">form 4</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <fieldset id="form1" class="tab-pane active">this is form 1</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="form2" class="tab-pane ">this is form 2</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="form3" class="tab-pane ">this is form 3</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="form4" class="tab-pane ">this is form 4</fieldset>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
```

You can see this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UME6D/6/)